# Viewing PDF (from URL) in android app within a webview intent

Tags: java, android, pdf, webview, uri

I am trying to view a PDF file remotely located from my device/the emulator. I have been doing quite a lot of research and been looking around stackoverflow on how to do this without having to download the PDF and then viewing the file that way.

This is the relevant code snippet for trying to do this:

```
if (url.contains("CreateQuoteDocument")) {
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url),"application/pdf");
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("something went wrong", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
E/something went wrong: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW ...
```

So having this said, I have two questions,

1. Why isn't this working?
2. Is there another way of doing this? (while not using google docs)

**EDIT**

The URL is properly formatted with http://www

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String myPdfUrl = "http://example.com/awesome.pdf";
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
Log.i(TAG, "Opening PDF: " + url);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: I specifically want to avoid using google docs to solve this issue, because it only gives you a limited amount of URL uses.

Comment: Ok. In that case, if you can view your url in any browser then, do:  webView.loadUrl(url);

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't this working?

You have not installed an app that contains an activity that supports that `Intent` structure (e.g., `application/pdf` for whatever scheme happens to be used by `url`).

> Is there another way of doing this?

You could install an app that contains an activity that supports that `Intent` structure. Of course, not all users will have such an app, but perhaps you are only intending to use your code personally, in which case there are no other users besides you.

Comment: So apps such as Adobe Acrobat reader, browser such as google chrome etc does not have this support? I have those installed at least.

Comment: @Jazzbaron: Adobe Acrobat looks like it supports `ACTION_VIEW` of `http` URLs for `application/pdf`. I do not know about the other apps. You might consider editing your question and providing the full stack trace, including the full error message.

Comment: `E/something went wrong: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=[link]http://www.beijerbygg.se/store/CreateQuoteDocument?mobile=true&catalogId=10552&quotationListId=291103&storeId=10202[link] typ=application/pdf }` this is the full error message. The user does have authority because he/she is logged in. Which is strange, I guess.

Comment: @Jazzbaron: You could try just `setData()` (or provide the `Uri` in the constructor) instead of `setDataAndType()` and see what results you get.

Comment: Hmm, it opens up an external browser and then tells me I don't have permission (despite being logged into my app). I guess the issue might be revolving around permission, although it really shouldn't be.

Comment: @Jazzbaron: "despite being logged into my app" -- unless you were logged in *via that specific browser*, you are not logged into the app, most likely, at least from the standpoint of that browser. There does not appear to be a session ID in your URL, suggesting that the user session is maintained by a cookie. Your code snippet shows signs of using `WebView`. For most (if not all) versions of Android, cookies in one app are independent of cookies in any other app.

Comment: That must indeed be the problem! The jury is still out on how to solve this. I'm going to try and just download the pdf file and then open it from local memory. I thought i'd get away easy with just opening it in a webview but seeing how the session does not apply in the browser...